# Constant value of ROM array

Tags: arrays, vhdl, constants

I am  trying to crate a 64 bit ROM `type ROM is array (7 downto 0, 7 downto 0) of std_logic;`

then I want create `constant R :ROM :=`.

Where `R(0, 7 downto 0 )` would be value of `"00010011"`,

`R(0, )`
`R(1, )` is selected by an 3bit pointer value and then it output by formula :

```
for i in 0 to 7  loop
      Data_Out(i) <= R(conv_integer(AArray),i);
end loop;.
```

But which ever way I am trying define the constant value of ROM I get an error, could someone point me to right way of defining constant for this array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For more complex initialization values, it is often helpful to make a function that returns the constant value to assign, like:

```
type ROM is array (7 downto 0, 7 downto 0) of std_logic;

function ROM_init return ROM is
  variable res_v : ROM;
begin
  -- Write code that assigns initial value to res_v
  return res_v;
end function;

constant R : ROM := ROM_init;
```

If an array of vectors is actually needed, you may consider instead doing:

```
type ROM is array (7 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
function ROM_init return ROM is
  variable res_v : ROM;
begin
  res_v(0) := "00010011";  -- Value from question
  -- Write more code that assigns initial value to res_v;
  return res_v;
end function;
constant R : ROM := ROM_init;
```

Note that the synthesis tool will probably not implement this as a ROM memory block, but simply as a simple logic network.

Comment: line `function ROM_init return ROM is` gives error "parse error, unexpected IS, expecting SEMICOLON" . Any idea why I am using ISE 14.7

Comment: Would it be because type ROM is in the package?

Comment: If the `ROM_init` function is placed in a package, then the public part of the package (`package`) should only declare `function ROM_init return ROM;`, and the implementation of the package (`package body`) should have the function implementation itself with `function ROM_init return ROM is ... end function;`.

Comment: Yes you are 100% right. I have just find this out and so far so good I will run small test bench and see if it works correctly now, thank you.